# Lagrange form of the Taylor series remainder

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0,1]$, twice differentiable on $[0, 1)$, and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$. Is it true that we can find a point $\xi\in (0,1)$ such that $f(1) = \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}$?

Now, if we add the condition that $f'$ needs to be continuous on $[0,1]$, this is just the Lagrange form of the Taylor series remainder. This extra condition is needed in order to apply the mean value theorem. However, is it possible to avoid the condition and MVT altogether? Or, is there a counter example where we cannot find a $\xi$ as above?